# FluentAssertions Throw() not listed to use

Tags: c#, nunit, fluent-assertions

I'm using FluentAssertions with NUnit and I realize that the method Throw() and other related methods is not listed for me to use. Do I have to install any other package to have access to this method?

I'm using the last release, 5.4.2, installed by NuGet.

Comment: Do you mean [`Should().Throw()`](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#exceptions) or [`Assert.Throws()`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws)?

Comment: Should().Throw()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it very clear, but `Should().Throw()` **has** to be applied to an [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) (or, as pointed out by @ArturKrajewski in a comment below, a `Func` and also `async` calls):

```
Action test = () => throw new InvalidOperationException();
test.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>();
```

So the tests could look like this:

```cs
public class AssertThrows_ExampleTests {
    [Test]
    public void Should_Throw_Action() {
        var classToTest = new TestClass();

        // Action for sync call
        Action action = () => classToTest.MethodToTest();
        action.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_Throw_Action_Async() {
        var classToTest = new TestClass();

        // Func<Task> required here for async call
        Func<Task> func = async () => await classToTest.MethodToTestAsync();
        func.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>();
    }

    private class TestClass {
        public void MethodToTest() {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        public async Task MethodToTestAsync() {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Or - in Fluent Assertions 5 or later - like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task Should_Throw_Async() {
    var classToTest = new TestClass();

    var test = async () => await classToTest.MethodToTestAsync();
    await test.Should().ThrowAsync<InvalidOperationException>();    
}
```

Comment: Since 5.5.0 also`Func<T>` supports `Should().Throw()` and similar assertions. Additionally, async scenarios for `Func<Task>` and `Func<Task<T>>` are supported as well.